# Push a uiviewcontroller on top of existing ViewController when my App becomes active again

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, storyboard, uiapplicationdelegate

My App has a multiple UIViewControllers that can be displayed by the user at any time.
The App can be also be started with a document (for example, an Attachment for mail App).

The scenario is the following:
- user starts the App and navigates inside the Application
- user puts the App in Background mode and he goes to Mail App
- From Mail App the user selects a mail with an Attachment and opens the Attachment with my App
- my App will enter in foreground and I would like to display the Attachment in a specific View Controller. 
- When the user has finished with the Attachment, he should be able to return to the previous state in the App (before attachment was opened).

I have overloaded the following methods from UIApplicationDelegate:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation {
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
```

Using these methods I'm able to find if there's a document to be displayed and if my App was already started or not.

My issue is to push the specific ViewController.

Below is an extract of my code to push the ViewController but nothing happen, any idea? How can I find the active ViewController in my App?

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    NSLog(@"applicationDidBecomeActive");

    if (_navigationCell != Nil) 
    {
        if ([DataCenter sharedInstance].isAppStarting == FALSE) 
        {
            // push a new navigation stack to display the cell from the navigation
            //PushArroundMeId
            UIWindow* window = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow;
            UIViewController* rvc = window.rootViewController;
            UIStoryboard* sb= [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboardiPhoneApp" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
            AroundMeViewController* avc = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"AroundMeViewControllerId"];

            if (avc != Nil) {
                [rvc presentViewController:avc animated:TRUE completion:NULL];
                window.rootViewController = avc;
            }
        }
    }
}
```